# ERROR - Calling addExpectationResult before specStarted

Tags: angular, typescript, jenkins, jasmine, protractor

Could any one help me to understand why am I having this issue on running protractor e2e test within a jenkins job but none if I run it locally?

[image]

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the issue.
Before more explanation about my objective: I want to create a kind of generic function in charge to run few common tests. those tests will vary according to the function params.

This function is supposed to be included within differents describe blocks (depending on the context)

Here is the code that generate this error:

```
export async function genericTest(
     params
): Promise<void> {

  **beforeAll(async () => {
   ....
  });**  

  it("Test 1", async () => {
   ....
  });
  it("Test 2", async () => {
   ....
  });
  it("Test 3", async () => {
   ....
  });

}
```

Apparently, the error occurs because of the presence of the beforeAll block.
why? I don't know yet :)

Hope someone have an answer, don't hesitate to comment. Thanks